# Why memory is not increasing?Has memory allocated physically？

Tags: objective-c, malloc, automatic-ref-counting, memset

I have tested the code in Xcode 10.3

```
- (void)loopObjectMalloc {
    while (1) {
        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }
}
```

I expect the OOM happened, but memory not increased. Is the alloc function not memset to the physical memory ?

Comment: obj will be released at the end of each while loop. Of course, memory won’t be increased.

Comment: @trungduc but the runloop keeps working, so when did release function happened?

Comment: As @trungduc has stated, by default Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is turned on.  Turn it off to test.  Update: and your last comment sounds like you are talking about autorelease functionality.

Comment: @Kylin.Zhang I think you are misunderstanding between the end of the loop and the end of function.

Comment: @trungduc yes I am confused about it, is there a autoreleasepool in the while loop？

Comment: disable ARC for file.m -fno-objc-arc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is turned on. So `obj` will be released at the end of each loop and make memory not be increased.

`obj` doesn't need to wait for every loops finished.

```
- (void)loopObjectMalloc {
    while (1) {
        // At the beginning of each loop, `obj` is created.
        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        // End of the loop, obj is released due to out of scope.
    }
    // End of function.
}
```

There is no need autorelease pool to release your object. `release` will be inserted to your code at compile time automatically.

> retain, release, retainCount, autorelease or dealloc cannot be sent to objects. Instead, the compiler inserts these messages at compile time automatically, including [super dealloc] when dealloc is overridden.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting#Objective-C

**Note**: *If you want to see OOM, turn off ARC.*

Comment: You should mention that this will only happen if ARC is turned on.

Comment: I think there do not have an autoreleasepool in while loop, I still have no idea why release happened

Comment: @Kylin.Zhang I don't think you understand what an "auto released" object is.  Your question and this answer has nothing to do with it.  Objective-C requires you to `retain` and `release` objects manually, unless you use ARC (now the default) and that is the functionality in-play in your question.  The ARC system sees the object going out-of-scope and inserts a `release` call to the object.  Hence it's managing the memory for you.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am understanding what you mean, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use use bridging functions to take ownership from ARC:

```
- (void)loopObjectMalloc {
    while (1) {
        CFTypeRef obj = CFBridgingRetain([[NSObject alloc] init]);
    }
}
```